# Copy cells from one worksheet to another based on the same reference number

Tags: vba, copy, worksheet

I am trying to copy rows into a different worksheet within the same workbook based on a matching reference number.
There are two worksheets: Books and MasterBooks
MasterBooks includes every column and row in the system, whereas Books includes only certain information.
I want a Macro to take the values from the Books worksheet and paste them in the MasterBooks worksheet in the right columns/rows.

Books worksheet:
[Books Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taEjf.png)

MasterBooks worksheet:
[MasterBooks worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuKZw.png)

Desired output in the MasterBooks worksheet:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG83H.png)

I currently have something but it only prints the data in the right column but without matching it to the ref number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! From your public data I see that this is your first question, great! But ..., it appears you have not visited the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get proper advice on what you can ask about and how to present your question. Most notably, you haven't shown your own effort to solve the problem. So, please, locate the `Edit` button beneath the tags of your question and edit your question to include your own effort.

Comment: Does it need to be vba? I think you can do it with vlookup formula.